# How to get border for a clipped Container() in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm using 'polygon_clipper 1.0.2' to clip my container.

```
Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    child: ClipPolygon(
          child: Container(
               color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
          sides: 6,
          borderRadius: 10,
         ),
   ),
```

Here I get a Filled Hexagon, whose vertexes are curved.

**I want a hexagon with just the border.**

The following code gives a container  having a rounded border.
I want similar result but sides should be 6.

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          border: Border.all(
                            width: 2, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                            ),
           ),
     height: 100,
     width: 100,
)
```

***Any Solution ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PolygonBorder`:

```
import 'package:polygon_clipper/polygon_border.dart';
```

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    shape: PolygonBorder(
      sides: 6,
      borderRadius: 10,
      border: BorderSide(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      )
    ),
  )
),
```